# how to do reflection in Nested object vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reflection, nested

I have an object that I accept and this object is a nested object which means it has properties that are also objects and so on.
I need a way to go through this object and its sons and their sons etc and for each of the properties check if its name is in the array I have with the names of some of the properties of the nested object and if so then I need the value of the property from the object.
Is there a way to do that?
I tried through reflection but could not move forward.
Some of the properties of the object I do not need so I check for on a property whether it is in my array

Comment: If you can't access the property directly, you could use reflection to call the getter.  The delegate is part of the `PropertyInfo` you get for the property.  If you give some more details on the problem, you'll get a more detailed solution (or better direction to the appropriate documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Create a method or function, and let it call itself.

Pseudo example with storage folders:

```
public sub Crawl(Path)
   for each folder in getfolders(path)
      crawl(Path)
   next
end sub
```

as you can see, this recursively crawls the filesystem into the deepest folders